# Visual Studio not showing .github folder

Tags: visual-studio, github-actions

I just pulled from a repository with a `.github` (Github Actions) folder. The folder is visible in Windows Explorer, but not in Visual Studio 2022 (c# console application solution). Why is that and how to see it in Visual Studio?

[image]

**Update:**
This is how it looks in Visual Studio, noet that `Show All Files` is enabled, yet the `.github` folder is not visible:
[image]

Comment: Do you see the `.git` directory? Did you turn on display of hidden files and folders?

Comment: I don't see the `.git` folder. Show all files is enabled. See updated screenshot above.

Comment: There’s a folder view all in solution explorer, can you see in that?

Comment: Are those directories in the solution directory or a project directory?

Comment: Ah yes, with the symbol right to the Home symbol I could switch the views! However that also changes what F5 does and maybe other things ):

Comment: @NineBerry In the solution directory

Comment: Why do you want to see the contents of the folders? They are managed by Git. No need to do anything with them directly.

Comment: @NineBerry The `.github` folder is not a git internal folder.

Comment: It's been like that for decades, so if you want a change, ask https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

The solution view shows the projects in the opened solution and their content but not additional folders in the solution folder.

You can use the folder view to view all folders and files in a certain folder. However, this will lose some features until you again select a solution from that view.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when using VS 2022. Even when I have Show All Files toggled, I can't see any of the files at the .sln folder level.

My work around is to just go to the folder or file itself and open in VS.

[image: Image of VS and Folders]

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to File / Open Folder and then navigate to your solution top level folder, like this:

[image: Nav to File/Folder/Open Folder]

...which gets you here:

[image: Where your folders are now ...]

Note you can see **one and only one** folder at a time.