# How to drill down to .github/workflows/jekyll-gh-pages.yml?

Tags: visual-studio, github-actions

How can I drill down and view all the `.yml` and other config files for editing in Visual Studio in the `.github` directory. Can I download such files into my IDE and push them back up when completed?

For example, I want to edit: `<MY_USER_NAME>.github.io/.github/workflows/jekyll-gh-pages.yml`:

[image]

I did attempt to clone the repository several times but the `.github/workflow` directory does not seem to be included. Is there a option in VS that I should be enabling to include this directory as part of my clone?

[image]

Comment: ...clone the repo?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did but the .github/workflow folder is not visible. Is it possible that it is hidden? If so, how can I "unhide" it?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74836074/3001761 (as that appears to be VS **not** VSC). Files and directories starting with `.` are often considered "hidden".

Comment: @NanoNet do you have directory `.workflows` when you look at Code section in GitHub Portal?